# com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, webservice-client

I am trying to do a PUT request call from code. I have used WebResource Class object like below:

```
final Client client = Client.create();
final WebResource webResource = client.resource(API_URL);
client.setConnectTimeout(Integer.valueOf(connectionTimeout));
client.setReadTimeout(Integer.valueOf(readTimeout));
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(apiUsername, apiPassword));
webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
webResource.header("Content-Length", 
String.valueOf(jsonInString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).length));
final ClientResponse response = webResource.put(ClientResponse.class, 
jsonInString);
```

here all the variables connectionTimeout, readTimeout, apiUsername, apiPassword, API_URL has proper values.

From the very last line it is trowing a SocketException as 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
The Exception is caught within ClientHandlerException catch block.

But when I am trying to hit the API_URL with other inputs from Postman Rest Client, I am geting success response.

Can anyone please help me understand why it is not working from code?

Comment: did you get any solution for this ? I notice its been long time since you asked , and actually i am facing same issue .

Answer (score 0):

Use JRE 7 as runtime environment. And create your Client like below and use. It will solve your problem.

```
package com.myoffice.util;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class ClientHelper {

    enter code here

    private static Client client = null;

    static{
        SSLContext ctx = null;
        try {
            //Protocol used is TLSv1.2. You may need other ..check target URL required Protocol
            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"));
            ctx.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
            client= Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while creating SSLContext", e);
        }
    }

    public static Client getClient(){
        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using https to solve? OP didnt mention HTTPS. Also, why JRE 7? Please explain how you got to this solution